# Where should I start my Django site inside of my virtual env?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I made a virtual environment to use Python 2.7 with Django 1.7, since the system's python is 2.6.6.

The virtual env has 5 folders inside of it by default. Should I keep all of them?

```
/bin/
/include/
/lib/
```

Where should I start my Django site? I'm thinking a new folder? Does it even matter or is there an industry standard?

Comment: it doesnt matter ...

Comment: None of those are default folders in a virtualenv.

Comment: and django site has nothing to do with virtualenv folder

Comment: You are right @DanielRoseman . Just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just start it in the main virtualenv directory.

You certainly shouldn't remove any of those subfolders: you need them for the correct functioning of the virtualenv and the code it contains.

Comment: So I'll just do `django-admin.py startproject django_project` right in this directory.